# Merge [tablesorter] and [jquery-tablesorter] tags

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, retag-request

Please merge [tablesorter](/questions/tagged/tablesorter) and [jquery-tablesorter](/questions/tagged/jquery-tablesorter) tags. Both refer to the same plugin.

Comment: Why was it created in the first place if it means the same thing?

Comment: @ProfPickle - Are you asking to the OP?

Comment: @hims Not essentially. I generally try to look at things from a different angle, but it's still a question of "Are they *exactly* the same?".

Comment: @ProfPickle I would assume them to be the same. The wiki descriptions are the same, except the other one is lacking a second line.

Comment: Perhaps instead of removing them, the results for one could be merged into the other's tag (like [tag:batch] and [tag:batch-file].